# Dynamically map an object to C# class

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nest

I am working with elastic search and added an EF Core interceptor on saving changes to get the details from context object and add it to Elastic search. As the context has more properties than needed, I was wondering if there is a way to map an object to a C# class on runtime.

Here is my code

```
    public async override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
                DbContextEventData eventData,
                InterceptionResult<int> result,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
               
                ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient = new ElasticSearchClient();
                foreach (var entry in eventData.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
                {
                      var response = await elasticSearchClient.IndexAsync(entry.Entity, idx => idx.Index(entry.Entity.GetType().Name));
                }
    
                return result;
            }

//entity.Entry is an object. For example: entry.Entity.GetType().Name can be a class of Student like below

    public class Student {
    
    int id;
    string name;
    int addressId;
    
    }

entry.Entity has all the details of student but it can have other details like details about addressname, createdAt, ModifiedAt.
```

entry.Entity has all the details of student but it can have other details like details about addressname, createdAt, ModifiedAt. I would like that entity.Entry to be mapped to student class. This mapping has to be dynamic at runtime based on the entry.Entity.GetType().Name because I am trying to do this for all the classes

Comment: `Entry.Entity` is already dynamic. It holds the entity class that is processed. There is one detail though depending on the query being executed navigation properties may not be loaded.

Comment: @Eldar But I get an error on elasticSearchClient.IndexAsync(entry.Entity, idx => idx.Index(entry.Entity.GetType().Name)); because entry.entity has more properties than needed or is part of the class so I was hoping I can map those properties. What do you suggest?